# Windows based testing using Winium. How is winium.storeapps different to winium.desktop?

Tags: webdriver, automated-tests

I'm doing Windows based testing using Winium.

How is winium.storeapps different to winium.desktop? How either of these can be integrated with Selenium?

Comment: Also, just to spread the word, Microsoft released their own WebDriver implementation for testing Windows desktop applications. You can find more info at https://github.com/microsoft/winappdriver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One is for Mobile and the other one is for Desktop applications. Both are based on WebDriver protocol (old spec called JSON Wire Protocol) and can be used with Selenium bindings. One can think of Winium drivers as one of the implementations of WebDriver, just like ChromeDriver or Appium are implementations of WebDriver.

- [Winium.StoreApps](https://github.com/2gis/Winium.StoreApps) is a selenium-based tool for testing applications on
  Windows Phone/Windows Mobile Emulators.
- [Winium.Desktop](https://github.com/2gis/Winium.Desktop) is a
  selenium-based tool for testings desktop applications on Windows
  Desktop.

We are currently finishing merging Winium.StoreApps and winphonedriver, next step will be to rename it into Winium.Mobile, so that there is no confusion.

**UPDATE** We finished merging drivers. Now we have [Winium.Mobile](https://github.com/2gis/Winium.Mobile) and [Winium.Desktop](https://github.com/2gis/Winium.desktop)

Disclosure: I am the author of Winium.StoreApps.

Comment: ([at]NickAb) Since you are author of one of the Winium libraries, could you please take a moment to answer this question, I would be grateful to you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47420814/is-winium-desktop-required-to-be-running-even-post-development