# Is Winium.Desktop required to be running even post development?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, desktop-application, ui-automation

I am new to the Winium world. I tried playing with **Winium.Cruciatus** which seems to be working fine but not perfect.
Hence, I am thinking to try **Winium.Desktop.Driver.exe** which I understand -

- is a Selenium-compatible wrapper for Cruciatus, and
- it is required to be running separately while development.

> However, I wanted to understand that once the development is done and
>   if the solution is deployed in production, will it
>   (***Winium.Desktop.Driver.exe***) still be required to be running in advance
>   for the solution to work?

**My requirement:** 
To automate the installation of a software on multiple VMs (domain joined) from one single VM.

**If (yes)**

{

- I think it may block the installation if it requires explicit Admin
  permission to run. As we cannot go on each machine to click on 'Yes',
  which defeats the purpose of automation.
- Because my environments will be Windows Server 2012 R2 and most of
  the time they are more restricted than a normal Windows like Win10.

}

**If (no)**

{

Any specific advantage of using **Winium.Desktop.Driver** vs only developing with **Cruciatus** library?

}

> **Note:** Can someone of high reputation please create a new tag - ***'Winium'*** as it seems this is required now as we already have few more questions
>   on Winium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Winium.Desktop is a testing tool, it is usually used to automate end-to-end or other functional testing scenarios. When it is used as testing tool, then it is only required during development/testing phase, not in production.

But if you use Winium.Desktop not for testing, but as an automation tool, for example to automate installation of a software, i.e. Winium.Desktop is a core part of solution that runs setup program and clicks next or something, then you will need Winium.Desktop during deployment phase.

Key advantage of Winium.Desktop over Cruciatus is that it provides Selenium interface and works as client-server, which is useful for test automation, as client-server can be scaled, and Selenium interface is well known and there are a lot of tutorials on how to use it.

If you just need to automate installation of some software (i.e. do not need to do actual testing using Winium), I would suggest looking into direction of one of IT infrastructure automation tools like Ansible, Chef, etc.

Regarding admin rights I suggest to open an issues at https://github.com/2gis/Winium.Desktop/issues describing your use case, probably there is a way to run it without admin rights or grant access only once.

Comment: Thanks Nick for the great explanation. In my case, we can't go with entirely 3rd party solution but only for homegrown solution. However, you helped me in understanding the key difference between Winium.Desktop vs Cruciatus. So far, I am able to proceed with Cruciatus and it's working fine :)